# MySQL fulltext search with a minimum number of matches per record

Tags: mysql, regex, full-text-search

I've been puzzling over this for a little while and I'm looking for feedback as to the best way to implement this.

Essentially I want to be able to search a database of documents and specify a keyword, for any record that matches the keyword I need to be able to specify how many times that keyword must occur.

The solution I'm about to start work on uses regex within the query to accomplish this, however from trawling stackoverflow I can see that this is possibly a little slow, the API needs to be able to do this very quickly since we're talking thousands of requests per minute.

Is there a faster way than using Regex or shall I pull out the VISA card and invest in some high end hardware?

To be clear I'm not tied to mysql I need to search a LOT of documents and match only those that have the keyword that occur X times.

Comment: We need more info from you to give an answer. Your current sql query especially, the record description of the fields you have in that query, and confirm it's a MySQL database.

Comment: Hi sorry if its a little vague, i'll revise, what i'm getting at is I need to say give me records that have X word in it that occurs X times, I don't have to use mysql but I have to do it fast!

Comment: have a look at http://sphinxsearch.com/.